# Through 1 someone through ffmpeg I need to combine 2 audio and add a picture (album) to it

Tags: image, audio, ffmpeg, merge

Through 1 whom through ffmpeg
I need to combine 2 audio and add a picture (album) to it

```
<--------->            1-audio
     <-------------->  2-audio
<------------------->  output
```

https://superuser.com/questions/1509582/ffmpeg-merge-two-audio-file-with-defined-overlapping-time

I looked at this link and it combined 2 audios.
Now I need to add a picture (album) to it

---

Here is the command that is using me

```sh
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=Ns|Ns[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

### Thanks to this, I was able to combine two audios into one.

I saw it this way

```sh
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1]adelay=5s|5s[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" -c:a copy -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" audio-out.mp3
```

```sh
1.mp3 - first audio (1:35 s)
2.mp3 - second audio (0:16 s)
1.png - picture (album) (170x170)
```

I got this error

`Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

---

## What I need?

### I need to add picture (album) to audio combined with this command

When I say picture (album), I mean exactly that.
This is clearly shown in the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMxqE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error, you need to remove `-c:a copy`. As the error message tells you, you cannot copy the output of a filter - you need to reencode the audio. Simply removing this will enabled transcoding, though you may wish to provide options to the mp3 encoder if you are after some specific configuration.

Then you will also need to remove `-map 0:0 -map 1:0` since these will be replaced by the output of the filter.

Finally, you need to add `-map 2:0` to map the image. This is because the image is now the third input rather than the second.

So the final command line will be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[1]adelay=5s|5s[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" -c:v copy -map 2:0 -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" audio-out.mp3
```